# Meteor changing variables in html [simple]

Tags: meteor

I know this is completely simple, but it's also completely is stumping me on why it isn't working. This gets to the point of rendering the html and showing Hello World with a message below "Welcome to chat" and a button "say hello back" but what it ISN'T doing is then change the message to "work".

I have a .js file which is:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
var message="welcome to chat";
function template(message){
Template.hello.greeting = function () {
return message;
};};
template(message);

Template.hello.events({
'click input' : function () {
  template("work ");
}
});

}
```

and a html follow as shown:

```
<head>
<title>chat</title>
</head>
<body>
 {{> hello}}
</body>
<template name="hello">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
{{greeting}}
<button value="Click">Say Hello Back!</button>
</template>
```

And it's embarrassingly simple but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know I shouldn't re render the page because the whole point of using meteor is for it's live html so what do I do have to do?

I figured out the main problem!

For my html I was using a button class but I should've been using a input type="button" instead!

Comment: I edited it - sorry about THIS stupid blunder. Essentially what's happening is that everything is going fine until I try to say template("work") which would mean that the message should equal work. It's only up to that part actually since before when I sent a message to the console right next to the template("work") it was sending the message fine so it's specifically about that template("work") which probably is about doing some other thing.

Answer (score 1):

To make it ["reactive"](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity) you should use [Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) that meteor provides. You can simplify your code to make it easier to read and understand.

> Session provides a global object on the client that you can use to
>   store an arbitrary set of key-value pairs. Use it to store things like
>   the currently selected item in a list.

You set the session variable to "welcome to chat" first. In your click event you would set the Session variable to "work". Then you would set the template to return the value of the Session variable when it changes. Your javascript could look something like this.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.set("message", "welcome to chat");

  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return Session.get("message");
  }

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      Session.set("message", "work");
    }
  });
}
```

This is untested but give it a try.

Comment: I'm actually using that and everything displays correctly except I see no visible with seeing "work"

Comment: @IGratch I see you figured out the answer, awesome! As a suggestion you should follow the pattern I have above as it makes it much more easier to read and follows what Meteor suggests. The function `template` you created is unnecessary and adds to complexity.

Answer (score 0):

i am not quite sure about what do you mean by "not working". But i am sure you will have to do following.

1. List item you need to prevent calling default event by the browser.
   ex:-

> ```
> Template.hello.events({
>    'click input' : function () {
>       //your code here 
>       return false;
>    }
> });
> ```

2 . use meteor [methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) instead of having template()